# sent data from ajax (vanilla version) doesn't store in $_POST in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I have this JS code ()

```
var obj = {
        first_name: 'cholo',
        last_name: 'yologs'
};
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("post", "recv.php"); 
xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(obj)); // or xmlHttp.send(obj);
```

and PHP code `recv.php`:

```
<?php
   $firstName = $_POST["first_name"];
   $lastName = $_POST["last_name"];
   echo $firstName." ".$lastName; 
?>
```

When I tried to run the page it says undefined index: `first_name` (and `last_name`).
Is there other method without using `file_get_contents('php://input')` then `json_decode()` in PHP or sending data in `FormData` object in JS but to store sent data to `$_POST` automatically?

Edit:
I also wanted to know why I can't access through `$_POST` just like sending the data through a `form`

Comment: When you say: *"store sent data"* - what do you mean exactly by **storing**?

Comment: i mean i can access the data using for example: $_POST['first_name']

Comment: something like `xmlHttp.send(Object.entries(obj).map((k,v)=>\`${k}=${v}\`).join('&'));` ... that may work, until it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a JSON-String representation, your PHP file should [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it to a StdObject:

```php
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($json);
    echo $data->first_name ." ". $data->last_name;
```

and the JavaScript:

```js
const obj = {
  first_name: "cholo",
  last_name: "yologs"
};

// FETCH

fetch("recv.php", {method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(obj)})
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);   // "cholo yologs"
  });
```

Otherwise, I suggest to use JavaScript FormData:

PHP file:

```php
<?php
   $firstName = $_POST["first_name"];
   $lastName  = $_POST["last_name"];
   echo $firstName ." ". $lastName;
```

JavaScript:

```js
const obj = {
  first_name: "cholo",
  last_name: "yologs"
};

// Convert your Object literal to FormData

const FD = new FormData();
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([p, v]) => FD.append(p, v));

// XHR

const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.addEventListener("load", () => {
  if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);   // "cholo yologs"
  } else {
    console.error("Error!");
  }
});
xmlHttp.open("post", "recv.php");
xmlHttp.send(FD); // Send the FormData
```

you should see finally `"cholo yologs"` in console.

Instead of XMLHttpRequest you could use the Fetch API:

```js
const obj = {
  first_name: "cholo",
  last_name: "yologs"
};

// Convert your Object literal to FormData

const FD = new FormData();
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([p, v]) => FD.append(p, v));

// FETCH

fetch("recv.php", {method: "POST", body: FD})
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);   // "cholo yologs"
  });
```

- [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)
- [Using FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)
- [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [Can I Use: Fetch](https://caniuse.com/fetch)
- [PHP json-decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: is it not possible to use directly the object?

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki added another example.

Comment: Ok so that's the only solution